# Align nested unordered lists next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a portfolio website using Foundation and Im running in a problem. I have a resume section with a UL containing 3 nested ULs. I want `resume__column` to have 33% width and aligned next to each other. The 33% width part is working but I can't figure out how to align them next to each other. (I use Foundation)

My HTML:

```
<div class="resume__content">
 <ul>
<li class="resume__column">
  <ul>
    <li><h5>Lorem ipsum</h5></li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="resume__column">
  <ul>
    <li><h5>Lorem ipsum</h5></li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="resume__column">
  <ul>
    <li><h5>Lorem ipsum</h5></li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

My SCSS:

```
.resume {
  &__content {
    @include grid-column(12, $center: true);
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
    }
    li {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
  &__column {
    display: inline;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    li {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not put them each in its own column? Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/162/), those frameworks are made to make your coding easy.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually way more easier indeed haha!